# UWP App Language is not changing dynamically

Tags: c#, uwp, resources, globalization

I have written code to change the language of a textblock to other language in a button click. But it is not changing when clicks on button. But seems to change when I restart the app or I click the button again. How can I change the language dynamically?

```
    private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeLanguage("fr");
    }
    private void ChangeLanguage(string language)
    {
        var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(language);
        Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
        if (Frame != null)
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
```

Comment: How are you using the localized strings in XAML? Could you post an example? And are you storing resources in RESX or RESW files?

Comment: using resw file.  <TextBlock x:Uid="txt_title2"   Text="" />

Comment: @nsds this behavior can be reproduced from the [official sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-resources-and-cd0c6eaa) Just changing the language will not change the text. You need to navigate to this page again to get the result. I suspect you've enabled the NavigationCache. In this way if you navigate it again it will not change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the language dynamicly:

```
        var resourceContext = ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
        var resourceMap = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("Resources");
        resourceContext.QualifierValues["Language"] = "fr";
        //if your string in .resw file called "Name.Text" you should swap "." to "/" in code or XAML
        var localizedString = resourceMap.GetValue("Name/Text", resourceContext).ValueAsString;
```

Now if you want to `x:Bind` it you have to create some `ObservableCollection` of localized items and change it with foreach `OnLanguageChange` event or some class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` that will ping all your language dependent resources.